# selecting subset array from the middle with a fixed size from multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subset

I would like to create a subset array with a specific size from various sized arrays, and I would like to take the subset array from the middle.

I thought about iterating for each array and calculating from the middle point via indexing, but its in iterative process and I would like to see if it is possible to do it with some clever numpy slicing that would vectorise the process.

for example, for the following arrays with the sub-array size=5:

```
ar1 = np.array([1,5,6,7,4,3,6,7])
ar2 = np.array([5,6,23,4,5,6,78,3,5])
ar3 = np.array([2,3,4,5,7,44,4,2,2,1,1,2,3])
ar4 = np.array([2,3,4,5,7])
```

I would like to get the following subarrays:

```
ar1 = np.array([5,6,7,4,3])
ar2 = np.array([23,4,5,6,78])
ar3 = np.array([7,44,4,2,2])
ar4 = np.array([2,3,4,5,7])
```

for example, I would like to avoid using code such as this:

```
middle = len(ar1) // 2
window = 5
ar1[middle - (window//2) : middle + (window//2) + 1]
```

Thanks!

Comment: To understand better, you _do not_ want to iterate through all the arrays but want to do it as a single operation?

Comment: @raghav710 not necessarily, I can cope with going over the arrays one by one, but i would like to make the slicing operation in a single command (if possible).

Comment: May be it helps you in some way `startIndex = (ArrayCount - Size)/2` and
`endIndex = startIndex + (size-1)` and then you can get the subset in a single loop.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldnt find a way to do that. I thought of a way that you could use `numpy.ma` followed by a `compressed()` but even there you need to know the indices